# Trigger.io Notification Module: No spinner shown using forge.notification.showLoading

Tags: notifications, trigger.io

According to the documentation and looking at the module on github, there should be a spinner (UIActivityIndicatorView) between .showLoading and hideLoading. But I only get the title and body. I validated that the success callback is called. What am I missing?

Comment: I get the same I think it might be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it's a bug.

The spinner works under iOS 6 and earlier but no longer shows up under iOS 7.

A fix will be in the next release of the notification module (v2.4)

Comment: Do you want issues opened on GitHub for Modules?

Comment: Great idea, yes please!